# How to set width of TextView for fill HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a TextView that the user can scroll horizontally with his finger. I create HorizontalScrollView and add TextView. But I can not set the width of TextView, so that it fills completely HorizontalTextView. How can this be achieved?
Thanks!

layout .xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBackspace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonface_backspace" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnBackspace"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnBackspace" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calculatedField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="75sp" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I understand. was necessary to add the following parameter to HorizontalScrollView:                                 fillViewport="true"